# Rearrange array in Javascript with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to reorder an Array with ES6.
For example:

```
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

When my starting number is 5, I want a new array like this:

```
    [5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4].
```

I am able to fix this by looping, comparing, slicing, glueing the thing back together.

However I've read some interesting array functionality with ES6 that might make this easier. But I'm having trouble putting this into practise.

Comment: Also, are you choosing the 5th (index 4) spot in the array because your starting Number is 5 or because it is the spot where 5 happens to be? Put another way, what should this method do with a startNumber of 5 and an input [1,2,5,3,4,6,7,8,9]?

Comment: What have you read and what seems to be the trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be

```
let newArr = [...arr.slice(arr.indexOf(5)), ...arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf(5))]
```

or

```
let newArr = [...arr];
newArr = [...newArr.splice(arr.indexOf(5)), ...newArr];
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure this is what you have in mind, but assuming you mean we are starting at 5 because its value (not position if you start counting at 1) is 5, the following should work (though maybe not the newfangled idea you wanted).

```
var startArr =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var startIndex=startArr.indexOf(5);//finds 5, if you meant just because it is the 5th. say startArr=5-1
if (startIndex!=-1){
    var a1=startArr.slice(startIndex);
    var a3=a1.concat(startArr.slice(0,startIndex));
    //a3 now contains what you wished for, you may console.log(a3) to see
}
```